# POSTMAN - Newman Run Iteration Json File on Specific Endpoint

Tags: json, api, postman, endpoint, newman

I have a postman collection that contains some endpoint. Something like this

`my-collection
   |- Get All Users
   |- Get User
   |- Delete User`

I also have some newman scenario/iteration json files (1. get-all-users.json, 2. get-user.json, 3. delete-user.json).

How do i run single scenario/iteration json file to specific endpoint on `my-collection`?

Lets say `get-all-users.json` run for `Get All Users` endpoint only, instead of run for all endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

By 'single endpoint', you mean running a single sub-folder for 1 iteration, say, 'Get All Users'. Right?

If so, you can export your `my-collection` as a JSON on your system (No need to individually export the sub-folders to get-all-users.json, get-user.json, delete-user.json).

You can use `--folder` option (See [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/api_testing_and_collection_runner/newman_intro#options) for reference). Just give the folder name you want to run, i.e., "Get All Users"

So, your newman command should be (your environment json and global json being   "env.json" and "global.json" respectively) :

```
newman run "<my_collection_path>/my-collection.json" --folder "Get All Users" -e "<env_path>/env.json" -g "<global_path>/global.json"
```

This way you should be able to run a requests in a single sub-folder at a time.